# Prove with Induction but without using the Binomial theorem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, binomial-coefficients

To prove with Induction but without using the Binomial theorem.

$$  {n\choose k }  \in \mathbb{N} $$
$  \forall n, k \in \mathbb{N}  $ with $ n \geq k $

I proved it already using the Binomial theorem but I am absolutely stuck right now, I dont know where to start here, can somebody help please..? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Go back to first principles and define $\binom n k$ as $\frac {n!} {(n - k)! k!}$. Then it remains to show that $k!$ is a divisor of the product of any $k$ consecutive integers, which (having looked at it) may not be immediately trivial.

Comment: They asked for an inductive approach, @PrimeMover.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only main recursive identity I can think is:

$$\binom{n+1}{k} = \binom{n}{k}+\binom{n}{k-1}$$

so maybe start here, as well as with the following definitions:

$$\binom{n}{0} = 1\\\binom{n}{1} = n$$

Also will likely involve a lot of "Addition is closed under $\mathbb{N}$".

Comment: Oh! It really helped me! Right now I am at the point where I have to prove that 
$ {n\choose k - 1 }  \in \mathbb{N} $ It may be easier then I think but does my assumption that $ {n\choose k }  \in \mathbb{N} $ help me with that?

Comment: Well, if proving $\binom{n}{k-1} \in \mathbb{N}$ lets you prove that $\binom{n}{k} \in \mathbb{N}$, you already have your inductive step! Now couple that with the initial conditions that I stated above, then you are done!

Comment: All right, so I can say that when I have my inductive step and I need to prove 
$ {n\choose k-1 }  \in \mathbb{N} $ I can just say that its true because $ (k-1) < n $ and that is simply so because of my assumption (inductive step)? P.S. Sorry for bothering with stupid questions...

Comment: Yes you are right.

Comment: Thank you so much! @Prometheus

Comment: @goldoner. In math, $no$ intelligible Q is a stupid Q.... Proof: Watch professional mathematicians working together.

Comment: This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, why not look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements? Please also read the [meta announcement](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/) regarding quality standards.